# nginx startup fail on mac osx 10.9 mavericks

Tags: macos, nginx, osx-mavericks

I've been using nginx for a few months without issue, but after upgrading to Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks, when trying to start nginx I get this:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

I tried to follow [these directions](https://serverfault.com/questions/548740/nginx-error-log-reports-bind-to-0-0-0-080-failed-48-address-already-in-use), but I'm not having much luck as my outputs seem a little different.

The output of:

```
ps ax -o pid,ppid,%cpu,vsz,wchan,command|egrep '(nginx|PID)'
```

is:

```
  PID  PPID  %CPU      VSZ WCHAN  COMMAND
 15015 12765  0.0  2432784 -      egrep (nginx|PID)
```

I've tried killing the process using that PID, but it never seems to die... Any ideas on how to get nginx running again? Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: try to see what process is listening to 80, maybe u installed apache or something like that

Comment: I have the same problem with "bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)". It doesn't give me permission denied if i change the port to 8000

Comment: Possible other solution to this error if (like me) Nginx starts up fine for you but your log still keeps getting spammed with this error: http://serverfault.com/a/548741/23206

Comment: That's not the nginx process, that's the terminal running that command. :)

Comment: @Adi To bind to ports under 1024 it must be run as an admin.

Comment: Thanks @JosephLennox

Comment: @Adi sudo fixed it for me for the (13: Permission denied)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Your `ps ... | egrep` command is finding itself, not an instance of nginx (look at the "COMMAND" column). Since port 80 is in use, it's likely some other program (maybe the Apache that comes with the OS?) is running and grabbing it. To find out, run:

```
sudo lsof -i:80
```

If it's the system Apache ("httpd") program, you can probably shut it down with:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

If that doesn't do it, more info will be needed to figure out what's grabbing port 80 and how it's getting started.

Comment: Still works 4 years later for those of you googlers.

Comment: 6 yrs and still going strong

Comment: 7 years still works. Question, is there any bad effects if i shutdown`httpd`?

Comment: @Justacoder No problem unless you're using it for something.

Comment: I ran `sudo lsof -i:80` and found the process I needed to kill by running `kill -9 <insert PID here>`. Then I was able to start up nginx successfully with `sudo nginx`.

Comment: 9 years still works

Answer (score 6):

Probably still nginx runnig and listening on port 80. try this command

```
sudo killall nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below command first to see which application is using 80 port.

`sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP`

`com.docke  1985       KOMP   25u  IPv6 0x4e18b4b0735f4091      0t0    TCP *:30299 (LISTEN)
com.docke  1985       KOMP   33u  IPv6 0x4e18b4b0735f21f1      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
com.docke  1985       KOMP   43u  IPv4 0x4e18b4b06bb5d721      0t0    TCP 127.0.0.1:6443 (LISTEN)
com.docke 43889       KOMP    8u  IPv4 0x4e18b4b06b933d41      0t0    TCP 127.0.0.1:63347 (LISTEN)
node      85239       KOMP   29u  IPv4 0x4e18b4b0954cbea1      0t0    TCP 127.0.0.1:4200 (LISTEN)`

Saw the below entry on the above result. And stopped docker.

> com.docke  1985       KOMP   33u  IPv6 0x4e18b4b0735f21f1      0t0
>   TCP *:80 (LISTEN)

And tried the below two command.

`sudo killall nginx`

`sudo nginx`

My application started working and started picking 80 port from my nginx.conf file.