# Can't pkill httpd in mac sierra

Tags: macos, apache

I got this error when trying to start apache

```
(48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
```

so I want to find out what is actually blocking the port and kill it

I did

```
ps aux | grep httpd
```

I saw this

```
mylaptop    45813   0.0  0.0  2432804    772 s005  S+    9:10AM   0:00.00 grep httpd
_www             45810   0.0  0.0  2455088    712   ??  S     9:09AM   0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
root             45809   0.0  0.0  2455344   3580   ??  Ss    9:09AM   0:00.11 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

I did

```
sudo pkill httpd
```

But when I did `ps aux | grep httpd` again the same process reappeared with different port

```
mylaptop    45819   0.0  0.0  2432804    772 s005  S+    9:10AM   0:00.00 grep httpd
_www             45817   0.0  0.0  2463280    716   ??  S     9:10AM   0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
root             45816   0.0  0.0  2463536   3588   ??  Ss    9:10AM   0:00.11 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

What is going on?

Comment: It might be the Apache that comes with macOS, managed (and auto-restarted) by launchd. If so, this is a duplicate of [nginx startup fail on mac osx 10.9 mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720237/nginx-startup-fail-on-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks).

Comment: mac come with apache?

Comment: Yep. Basic web serving used to be configurable in the Sharing preference pane; nobody used it, so they took it out of the GUI, but Apache is still there as part of the standard macOS system.

Comment: how to stop it? this is unbelievable, it was working and suddenly my apache broke, maybe system update causing that?

Comment: I don't see how a system update could have started it. We don't even know if that's what you're seeing, it's just a guess! Try running `sudo launchctl list | grep 45816` (replacing "45816" with whatever the current root process's PID is); if it's being started by launchd, that should show it's job label.