# Why is Laravel project showing 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.17.2?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, valet

I recently update node on my mac, and strangely, all my laravel projects have stopped working. I use Valet for my Laravel project. So when I try to open local.myproject.test it shows 502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.17.2

Screenshots of Nginx error logs are as follows.
[log/php-fpm.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aGLC.png)

[image: log/nginx/error.log]

I tried to check what was running on port 80 with the command sudo lsof -i:80 , here is the output

[image]

Comment: Have you tried googling the given messages? Obviously, port 80 is already bound to another service

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nginx startup fail on mac osx 10.9 mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720237/nginx-startup-fail-on-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks)

Comment: already added in question body please check